# Looping the arraylist? Using Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I have an arraylist,

```
   ArrayList lists = new ArrayList();
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("A");
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("I");
        lists.Add("D");
        lists.Add("H");
```

now i am trying to remove the arraylist items with no of count.
 that means if i have count =8 then loop will run for 8 times and remove the arraylist item  like :

```
   1 2  3  4 5 6 7 8 
   S A  S  I D H S **A**

   A is removing from arraylist

  after that  arraylist is  S S I D H only again

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
   S  S I D H S S **I**

   I is removing from arraylist

   like this upto single item in arraylist .
```

i used for condition but no use.
my code is

```
     ArrayList lists = new ArrayList();
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("A");
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("I");
        lists.Add("D");
        lists.Add("H");

        int lent =8;

        for (int k = 1; k <= lent; k++)
        {
            if (k == lent)
            {
                if (lists.Count == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {


                    lists.RemoveAt(k-1);                        
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: your arraylist length is 6 and your lent is set to 8 ?? am I missing something ?

Comment: yes, arralylist is 6 and count is 8

Comment: this makes no sense to me .. what are you even trying to do ? why do you have an empty else{} block ?

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Get the **count** of list and check against the length you define. if its greater than the list count get the index of item that you need to remove by the difference of two. Otherwise you can take the your define length as index.then use **lists.RemoveAt(INDEX);**

Comment: i am trying to do, loop will run for 8 times then i have to remove the item in a array,

Comment: Why do you check if (lent > 6) ? lent is *always* gonna be bigger than 6..?

Comment: yeah your right Jane Doe

Answer (score 0):

In your example in the array list there are only 6 objects (strings) inserted in the array,
but you defined lent as 8, why?

why dont you do lists.lenght

Comment: Is this answer the question?? Also there is nothing called **lists.lenght** you can do **lists.Count** instead

Comment: lent is not the count of arraylist it is different

Comment: lent is the number, that time of loops will be happen

Comment: This was not an answer it was my fault write like the answer. When you use diferent languages sometimes you mix them. Yes you are right humpty dumpty you can do list.count.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to do.. but the following code will simply loop through the array and remove every element at index i.

```
        ArrayList lists = new ArrayList();
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("A");
        lists.Add("S");
        lists.Add("I");
        lists.Add("D");
        lists.Add("H");

        for (int i = lists.Count - 1 ; i >= 0; i --)
        {
           lists.Remove(lists[i]);
        }
```

it will start removing items at index 5, so that means "H" will be the first item to be removed.

Comment: If you doing this way, why using **for-loop**?? you can simply use **lists.RemoveRange(startindex,length)**

Comment: no it not start removing from last it should start with first that means from "s"

Comment: then you can do as @huMptyduMpty said and just use * lists.RemoveRange(0, 6);*